# HTML to display only dynmap chat, possible port to mobile application

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have spent the past week trying to HTTP PUSH chat to a specific minecraft server's Dynmap chat, with no success. I"m still learning HTML/CSS, and know enough of JS to get by. Recently I found this .js script (http://pastebin.com/3UWEpHMW) which I'm trying to implement into a small project here (http://www.codecademy.com/betaCoder42490/codebits/FM1fgs) Don't go and say that before trying something big like this I should go learn everything first, because THIS is my preferred method of learning, doing something big and having to do research. I've just gotten stuck. 
things I possibly understand:
1)dynmap plugin uses server-side .js scripts to JSON.stringify the data that you send.
2)said 'data' is 
`'{"name":+JSON.stringify(pname?pname:" ")+',"message": '+JSON.stringify(message)+'}';`
3) it might be possible to HTTP PUSH straight into the `<div>chatinput</div>`
4)I've found out about `xmlhttprequest`
With that said, what specific things should I look into/research/learn that will help me achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

I am currently working on something similar to that. In fact, this can work if you are using the standalone version of DynMap because you can then send an HTTP POST request to /standalone/sendmessage.php but that does not work with the integrated webserver as this one does not use the PHP files.

You could still try to reference to /js/chat.js but I am not yet 100% sure how the plugin handles these javascript files as i have not dug trough the whole web part of it.

Answer (score 0):

I've dug through the dynmap code and figured out how to interact with some of it's methods. I used socketIO. 
You can send messages with

```
$(dynmap).trigger('sendchat', 'hello dynmap!');
```

`You can read messages from other players using:

```
$(dynmap).bind('chat', function(event, message) {
    //message.text and message.name are useful here.
}
```

You can access these methods by placing a socket connection on the dynmap site. Then you can interact between the dynmap/server with live updates. The basic idea could be used in mobile dev.